# How to get PostgreSQl log

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How can I get log information from PostgreSQl server?

I found ability to watch it in pgAdmin Tolls->ServerStatus. Is there a SQL way, or API, or consol way, to show content of log file(s)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am command line addict, so I prefer “console” way.

Where you find logs and what will be inside those depends on how you've [configured your PostgreSQL cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html). This the first thing I change after creating a new cluster, so that I get all the information I need and in the expected location.

Please, review your `$PGDATA/postgresql.conf` file for your current settings and adjust them in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

The [`adminpack`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html) extension is the one providing the useful info behind pgAdmin3's server status functionality.